# How to draw matplotlib graph in eclipse?

Tags: python, eclipse, matplotlib

I can draw matplotlib graph in command line(shell) environment, but I find that I could not draw the same graph inside the eclipse IDE. such as `plot([1,2,3])` not show in eclipse, I writed `show()` in the end but still not show anything 
my matplotlib use GTKAgg as backend, I use Pydev as plugin of eclipse to develop python.

Comment: possible duplicate of [interactive matplolib through eclipse](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3918889/interactive-matplolib-through-eclipse)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as mp
mp.ion()
mp.plot(x,y)
mp.show()
```